# Can't get past HTTP request in Node

Tags: node.js

So, here is the problem. I found how to do http request in Node.js, so that I could download and parse remote JSON file. It all works fine but nothing happens after that. I have a function and in that there is if condition that doesn't get executed. It simply cannot get past the http request. Is there something I am missing?

```
var remoteStamp;       
if (typeof force == "undefined") {
  var timeurl = "http://" + parsedconfig.weburl + "/timestamp.json";
  request(timeurl, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(body.timestamp);
    remoteStamp = body.timestamp;
  });
}
if (remoteStamp < parsedconfig.timestamp || force == "local") {
//something should happen here, all the values check out - still nothing happens
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using callback so all the code which you want to execute after request is completed should be inside the callback

```
var remoteStamp;       
if (typeof force == "undefined") {
  var timeurl = "http://" + parsedconfig.weburl + "/timestamp.json";
  request(timeurl, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(body.timestamp);
    remoteStamp = body.timestamp;
    if (remoteStamp < parsedconfig.timestamp || force == "local") {
    //something should happen here, all the values check out - still nothing happens
    }
  });
}
```

Or you can use request-promise library to do this in promises. https://github.com/request/request-promise

On how to use promises: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you, now I get it.